# Replace script attr or link

Tags: javascript

Hello friends i have this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://thompsonlaw.formstack.com/forms/js.php/tho_lionlaw_com_v2"></script>` form link in many wordpress pages, i would like to either replace the link with custom link or to be able to replace "src" attr to something else to stop it from loading

please note: that i already have tried this using script_loader_tag, but it replaces all attrs instead of that specific link from pages

thanks to all in advance

Comment: i have more than 70+ pages having that link and its not easy to edit all pages to remove it so i am looking for a easy way around

Comment: How is this being added to the pages? Is it in the post content? Via the enqueue script system? A part of the theme templates?

Comment: @TomJNowell its in page content in raw html avada theme is used

Comment: I see, then this isn't something a code change can help you with, what you need is a search replace tool

Comment: @TomJNowell Preg_replace? or str ?

Comment: A database search replace tool, a PHP function will not do the job

Answer (score 0):

Much like all programming, there are many ways to go about solving this. One way is using an id tag id = "script_lionlaw" (or name is whatever you want) within the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://thompsonlaw.formstack.com/forms/js.php/tho_lionlaw_com_v2" id = "script_lionlaw"></script>
```

You could then use jquery (or some other means) to grab the tag and then replace it with whatever you want.